# Print server does not show up on router's attached devices

Tags: router, print-server

Recently I bought a new more powerful wireless N router, DLink DIR 628. So I removed all connections from the previous router (Netgear WGT624) and connected them as they should be to the DLInk router. Everything works fine except for the print server.

I have Hawking print server connected to HP Laserjet 6P parallel port printer. It works well with the Netgear router. But when I connect it to the DLInk router, it does not even show up in the LAN computers list. I am not sure what is going on.

There is a utility called PSAdmin that can talk to the Hawking print server if I switch to Netgear router. With that utility, I can get the assigned IP address to the print server. But when switching to DLink router, even the PSAdmin fails to find the print server.

I have been trying various things for last couple of days in vein. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Set the print server to static ip via your internet browser's print server menu.

Set the ip  address of the print server higher than the usual range of dynamic addresses distributed by the router.

When configuring the printer port setting in the control panel make it the same as the print server ip address. eg 10.1.1.12

However the print server's ip address will not show up on the D-link router.Even so it should still  work with wireless and Ethernet providing all the port address are set the same on each computer eg 10.1.1.12